# Jupyter Notebook - Matplotlib keep running

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I just started to use `Jupiter Notebook` to learn `Python`. while I am trying out `matplotlib` with this basic code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

The kernel just keep running and nothing happen. How to resolve this? Is there an dependency issue? My newly installed `matplotlib` is 1.5.1, `python` is 3.5.2, `numpy` is 1.11. Running on MacBook Pro 10.11(El Capitan).

Comment: Is the jupyter server running on the same machine as your web browser? Without `%matplotlib` magic, this will open a plot window on the server machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Visualize the plots created by the matplotlib in **Jupiter Notebook  or ipython notebook** you have add one extra line at the beginning.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
%matplotlib inline
```

If your matplotlib **version is above 1.4, and you are using IPython 3.x** you have to use the below code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
```

Comment: Are you referring to an older version or newer version with "IPython 3.x" compared to your first half? I believe notebook works in both, and gives interactivity

Answer (score 0):

It likely showed you a Matplotlib popup, with the IP(y) logo. To show it inline you have to use some IPython magic. Run this in a cell somewhere:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

After you close the popup it will finish the statement in your kernel

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes takes time until the kernel starts.

Check that the code is color-highlighted. If it is, it means that the kernel is running. Evaluate the cell again. You will notice a `*` beside that cell, meaning it's running.

And one more thing: Sometimes the plot is displayed but its window hides behind the notebook... Access it from the task bar